# pyODBC statement appearing to run but not affecting table

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I have the following script running;

```
from os import getenv
import pyodbc
import os
import sys

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('''
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=myServer\SQLEXPRESS;
DATABASE=myTable;UID=myID;PWD=myPassword''')

cursor = cnxn.cursor() #makes connection
cursor.execute("""

            UPDATE ShowroomCal
                SET ShowroomCal.isbusy = 'Yes'
            FROM ShowroomCal
                JOIN calendarbookings on calendarbookings.date=showroomcal.style112 AND calendarbookings.showroom=ShowroomCal.showroom_name
                WHERE CalendarBookings.date = showroomcal.style112 and ShowroomCal.Year='2018'
                """) #runs update statement

row_count = cursor.rowcount #counts afrfected rows
status_msg = "result returned. {} row(s) affected."
print(status_msg.format(row_count)) #prints affected rows

cnxn.close()
```

The notebook cell returns "3 row(s) affected." yet the table being updated doesn't change when viewed in SQL Express.

I have since independently run the statement from SQL Server Management in a Query Window and it instantly changed the three rows that would have been affected so I know that the data in the table exists to be changed and that the statement works - at least from a SQL standpoint.

Can someone spot any errors from a Python perspective?

Comment: Is it necessary to make a commit ?

Comment: You need to commit the changes using `cnxn.commit()` after executing the query.

Comment: Ah! I had 'GO' in the SQL statement before errors lead me to remove it, I should have realised I needed to replace it with something else! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scratch'N'Purr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6245650/scratchnpurr) provided the answer for me, thanks very much.

If anyone else is having the same issue it's the lack of

```
cnxn.commit()
```

After the statement that is the problem. I have since tested this and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Note that you can accept your own answer by clicking the check mark icon.

Comment: Thanks, Gord - don't I have to hold off for a few days?

Comment: I don't recall if the system enforces a waiting period. If so, you can always do it later.